# Trying to find a way to dynamically add items to a check list box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

I have a check box list that I'm populating with values from a table in my database. I've added the ability for users to add items to the check box list through a modal popup:

```
<section class="submodal submodalWindow" id="popupFour" style="margin-top: -142px; height: 388px; width: 400px; border: solid; margin-left: -627px; top: 42%; left: 68%">
                <section class="submodalWrapper" style="height: 342px">
                    <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Add a Document</h1>

                    <hr />

                    <div class="card pmd-card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <!-- Basic Information -->
                            <div class="details-tab">

                                    <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
                                        <label class="pmd-list-subtitle">Document</label>
                                        <asp:TextBox class="form-control" runat="server" ID="tbDocument"></asp:TextBox>                                        
                                    </div>

                                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel33">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnPacketAdd" OnClick="btnPacketAdd_Click" class="d-none d-sm-block btn btn-sm btn-success shadow-sm"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-sm text-white-50" style="padding-right:10px"></i>Add</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>

                            </div>

                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-lg btn-success shadow-sm modalButton" Style="margin-left:95px; margin-top:20px"><i class="fas fa-backward fa-sm text-white-50"></i>Back</asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <a class="subcloseBtn">CLOSE X</a>
            </section>
```

My issue is that when I try to add a new item through the modal popup, it does not update the checkbox list right away. I would have to close the application and run it again for the newly added items to appear. I've already set `AutoPostBack=True` as per some posts online, however, I may be missing something here as this is my first time doing this. The code below is how I'm storing the items to my table:

```
Protected Sub btnPacketAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPacketAdd.Click
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HRRecruitmentDBConn").ToString())
            ' Create a command object.
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

            ' Assign the connection to the command.
            cmd.Connection = conn

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblCredentialingPacket (Packet_Item, Status) VALUES (@Packet_Item, @Status)"

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", 1)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Packet_Item", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 150).Value = tbDocument.Text

            conn.Open()

            cmd.Connection = conn



            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I created a function called `BindCheckBoxList()` which binds the datasource to my checkboxlist so whenever I add a new item from the modal popup it automatically updates the checkbox list.